# Objective-C ARC property redeclaration confusion

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have the following code:

```
// MyObject.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id property;
@end

// MyObject.m
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MyObject ()
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) id property;
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize property = _property;
@end
```

This generates the following compiler warning and error:

```
warning: property attribute in continuation class does not match the primary class
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) id property;
^
note: property declared here
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id property;
                                   ^
error: ARC forbids synthesizing a property of an Objective-C object with unspecified ownership or storage attribute
```

However, if I change the class continuation's property redeclaration to have a storage qualifier of `weak`, no warnings or errors are generated. However, (alarmingly?) the generated code for `-[MyObject setProperty:]` calls `objc_storeStrong` rather than my expected `objc_storeWeak`.

I understand that as of LLVM 3.1, the default storage for synthesised ivars is `strong`. I suppose my question is this: why is the codegen favouring the declaration in the header over my redeclaration in the implementation? Secondly, why does it complain when I redeclare as `copy`, but not `weak` or `assign`?

Answer (score 3):

I understand your question bellow...

- You want to readwrite myproperty in MyObject class member method.
- But, want to readonly myproperty from other class.

---

// MyObject.h

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
{
@private
    id _myproperty;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) id myproperty;
@end
```

---

// MyObject.m

```
#import "MyObject.h"

@interface MyObject ()
// @property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) id myproperty; // No needs
@end

@implementation MyObject
@synthesize myproperty = _myproperty;


- (void)aMethod
{
    _myproperty = [NSString new]; // You can read & write in this class.
}

@end
```

---

// Ohter.m

```
#import "MyObject.h"

void main()
{
   MyObject *o = [MyObject new];
   o.myproperty = [NSString new]; // Error!! Can't write.
   o._myproperty = [NSString new]; // Error!! Can't acsess by objective c rule.
   NSString *tmp = o.myproperty; // Success readonly. (but myproperty value is nil).
}
```